# Adding Dynamically Control in WPF on Button click

Tags: c, wpf

[image]*I have three Text Box called TxtDocumentTitle1, TxtDocumentTitle2,TxtDocumentTitle3*  lastly there is a Add More Button. Client can Click Add more Button so that it generates Text box naming TxtDocumentTitle4. If more needed he/she can Add more Text Boxes.

*Sample XAML code of View*

```
<Grid Height="450" Width="700" Background="White">

   <TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left"   Margin="67,20,0,0" Name="textBlocKname" Text="Document Title1:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="110" />
   <TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="67,87,0,0" Name="textBlockAddress" Text="Document Title2:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="110" />
   <TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="67,154,0,0" Name="textBlockCompanyName" Text="Document Title3:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="110" />
   <TextBox Height="46" Margin="67,37,87,0" Name="txtDocumentTitle1" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="24" />
   <TextBox Height="46" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="67,106,0,0" Name="txtDocumentTitle3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="546" FontSize="24" />
   <TextBox Height="46" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="67,171,0,0" Name="txtDocumentTitle2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="546" FontSize="24" />                 

   <Button Content="Add More" Height="37" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,223,87,0" Name="btnAddmore" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="102" />

        </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this easily via `Binding`. if your Window does not have a ViewModel open your window's xaml.cs and make it like this:

```
 public Window1()
 {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
 }

public ObservableCollection<TextBoxVm> Items { get { return _items; } }
private ObservableCollection<TextBoxVm> _items = new ObservableCollection<TextBoxVm>();
```

if not, just add the two last lines to the viewModel of your window.

Now you need to define a class derived from `DependencyObject` and name it say `TextBoxVm`. create two `DependencyProperty`s in it (use propdp snippet) as follows:

```
public string Text
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
    set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(TextBoxVm), new UIPropertyMetadata("default text",
    (d,e)=>
    {
        var vm = (TextBoxVm)d;
        var val = (string)e.NewValue;
        MyDataService.FindAndUpdateItemInDatabase(vm.Id, val);//you can access database with something like this
    }));

public string TitleText
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(TitleTextProperty); }
    set { SetValue(TitleTextProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleTextProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("TitleText", typeof(string), typeof(TextBoxVm), new UIPropertyMetadata("default title"));
```

This would be the xaml code:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <WrapPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding TitleText}"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Text}"/>
            </WrapPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Now the only thing left is to write Button logic. simply add TextBoxVm to Items when Button is clicked.

```
 Items.Add(new TextBoxVm { 
     TitleText = string.Format("Document Title{0}:", Items.Count+1)
 });
```

### Edit Note:

this approach is standard MVVM (expect for the button click event, which should be done using `Command`). So if you want to add controls in code (which is not recommended) search this :

add control to wpf grid programmatically.

Comment: **Thanx** Biz. This Add text Box Dynamically. Can you tell me what will be the name of the Dynamically added text Box. Suppose i have TxtDocumentTitle3 now i click add more button then the added text box name will be txtDocumentTitle3. and so on

Comment: You're welcome. in MVVM it's not recommended to use Name for controls. in fact this approach does not allow you to set name to items of `ItemsControl` instead you can manage everything in ViewModel (in this example TextBoxVm class and the class body of Window.xaml.cs). if you provide more info on why and where Name should be used I can help you with it.

Comment: Bizz i just added the Screenshot of my work. That you mean i can bind TextBoxVm class property to insert Dynamically added text box content into the Db.

Comment: I updated the answer. take a look at last piece of code (button click event)

Comment: sorry my internet went dead! I also updated dependency property of Text and added a callback. so when you change the Text in the window (and lost focus from the text) the updateAndAdd... function is called

Comment: **Thanx Very Much **  Bizz this Works Out :)

Answer (score 0):

**Above Answer from Bizz Gives Solution of My Question ** Beside that it Rise me a Question  about **DependencyObject ** after Few Research i found this about Dependancy Object which may be Helpful for New comer to WPF like me :)

**What is DependencyObject??**

Dependency object is the base object for all WPF objects. All the UI Elements like Buttons TextBox etc and the Content Elements like Paragraph, Italic, Span etc all are derived from Dependency Object.

Dependency objects are used for WPF property system. By default, what ever the property system we have in DOT Net CLR is very basic. But Dependency properies provide lots of addtional features/services to support Data Binding.

Once you create any property as a dependency property, then automatically you get following feature implemented for you. ie. Change Notification, Validation, Call Back, Inheritance, DataBinding, Styles, Default Values etc.

If you need to implement all these features on your own for all properties where you need these feature, then it will be a big process and head ache for you. So, these all coming out of the box from Dependency Object class.

Basically dependency object class contains a dictionary. So, when ever set any value or retrieve value, then it will change the value or read from that Dictionary. So, it is nothing but a key value pair.

**For Detail Info abouT DependencyObject**

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140620/WPF-Tutorial-Dependency-Property
http://www.pinfaq.com/32/what-is-dependency-object-in-wpf-where-should-i-use-it